# why MOQ framework overrides all virtual methods - c#

Tags: c#

I'm new to MOQ in c#.
Here is my code:

```
   public class CustomerBase
    {
        private List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
        public const int MAX_CUSTOMERS = 100;

        public int CustomerCount()
        {
            return customers.Count();
        }

        public void AddCustomer(string name, string email)
        {
            if (CustomerCount() >= MAX_CUSTOMERS)
            {
                return;
            }
            Customer cus = new Customer(name);
            customers.Add(cus);
            SendEmail(email);
        }

        public virtual void SendEmail(string email)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestAddUser()
        {
            Mock<CustomerBase> m = new Mock<CustomerBase>();
            m.Setup(x => x.SendEmail("k")).Verifiable(); // bypass send email because email is server is not setup
            m.Object.AddCustomer("max", "k@g");
            Assert.AreEqual(1, m.Object.CustomerCount());
        }
  }
```

The test passes. As soon as I make the CustomerCount virtual, the test fails because it that method starts to return zero.
Does anyone know why and how to prevent this behaviour?

---

*Updated code - using internal assembly fails:*

```
   [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("UnitTestProject1")] // make the test assembly internal
namespace MoqSmple1
{
    public class CustomerBase
    {
        private List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
        public const int MAX_CUSTOMERS = 100;

        internal virtual int CustomerCount()
        {
            return customers.Count();
        }

        public void AddCustomer(string name, string email)
        {
            if (CustomerCount() >= MAX_CUSTOMERS)
            {
                return;
            }
            Customer cus = new Customer(name);
            customers.Add(cus);
            SendEmail(email);
        }

        internal virtual void SendEmail(string email)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestAddUser()
        {
            Mock<CustomerBase> m = new Mock<CustomerBase>();
            m.Setup(x => x.SendEmail("k")).Verifiable(); // bypass send email because email is server is not setup
            m.Object.AddCustomer("max", "k@g");
            m.CallBase = true;// keep the default behaviour of virtual methods except the ones skipped
            Assert.AreEqual(1, m.Object.CustomerCount());
        }
    }
}
```

*update*
I figured out:

- I needed a public key
- I needed to make the methods internal *protected* virtual

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to set `<YourMock>.CallBase = true`. [Here is a good article on `CallBase`](http://www.jamie-dixon.co.uk/tdd/partial-mocking-in-moq-using-callbase/)

In a nutshell, Moq will create a proxy for all virtual methods by default, and setting CallBase to true keeps the default implementation unless you explicitly ask for a proxy.

Comment: Thanks. If I may ask a follow up question; using MOQ requires you to change some of the production code to be public virtual. Are there any techniques to avoid doing so?

Comment: You can change them to internal virtual and use InternalsVisibleTo[TestAssembly]. But, otherwise you have to use something more powerful (RhinoMocks)...which leads me more often to question the design anyway...just keep that in mind

Comment: I tried that suggestion using separate assemblies as internal. That causes the tests to fail. For some unknown reason, it causes MOQ not to override the method that I wish to skip.

Comment: You used: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx ? I've used this numerous times without fail....

Comment: @max Hrmmm. The documentation has you putting the attribute on the class, however I've always added it to the assembly.cs via: `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("FriendlyAssembly, PublicKey=000...000")]` I'm not sure if the PublicKey would help or not, though. Let me know if moving it to Assembly.cs helps

Comment: I think it might have something to do with signed/unsigned assemblies. So, you may need to look at the documentation along those lines...something like: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384966.aspx ?